# dual stage charger, is fuse needed?

Tags: batteries, charger, fuses

I have a basic circuit: battery, fuse off (+)lead, 4 lights in parallel.

My question is, when charging is a fuse needed?

Also in the battery/charger circuit, which side is considered positive?

Update:

Ive obtained a 2amp glass fuse, as recommended, but it is a high voltage fuse.
Checking the voltage off the plugged-in charger(12V/1AMP), with its 2amp high-voltage glass fuse on, reads at 14.5V.

I attach the charger to a 12V battery, which has a 10amp blade-type low-voltage fuse, off the positive cathode.

The charging light doesn't come on when connected; however the charged-complete led came on when I it was being checked with the voltmeter.

here is my system:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fulsqP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

charger + fuse:
[image: charger+fuse]
a weather-proof connector between battery and charger:
[image: battery to charger connector]
the battery with text:
[image: battery]
top of battery can see fuse off cathode and a quick-connector type:
[image: battery blade fuse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you have something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJK0S2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you don't, then do provide more information.

When charging is a fuse needed? I'd say yes! Basically, fuse is there to protect the battery from being damaged by the load. Batteries can often provide large current when shorted and if somehow the load gets shorted, battery would be protected by the fuse from the short. If the battery is charging, and the load somehow gets shorted, then you'd have even worse situation. Not only would battery provide current for the short, but charger would as well. The result would be melting cables and damage to the battery and the charger due to overcurrent.

Next, about the "positive" part. That, as always, depends on perspective since voltage needs a reference point. I'd  call positive terminal of the battery positive and I'd call the terminal of the charger connected to the positive terminal of the battery positive as well. They're both more positive than their own negative terminals and are commonly marked as positive, which means that others will easily understand about which terminal you're talking.

If you explained to us why you want to know which terminal would be which, we could provide more information. For example if you measured voltage between the positive terminal of the charger and the positive terminal of the battery, while the charger is running, you'll see that the charger's terminal is more positive than the battery's positive terminal (making the positive terminal of the battery negative). In such situations I'd still keep the designations I introduced in previous paragraph since changing them could add confusion into conversation.

Comment: I would put the fuse directly on the battery terminal, between the battery and the positive bus, or add a second fuse between battery + and charger +, both fuses to be as near the battery as possible, to protect all wiring (and the battery) in case of a fault anywhere.

Comment: @Peter Bennett Me too.

Comment: Hi, the diagram is correct.  However, when charging the battery there will be no load.  It will just be a charger and battery.  I wanted to know if fuses are needed if just charger and battery? (sorry I was not more specific)  Also, in looking at your diagram, I guess I was confused about how to connect the charger to battery- ie positive to positive.  (again sorry and thankyou)

Comment: Is it ok to use a 10amp fuse on a 1amp charger/12V battery with no load?  Would a 10amp fuse allow for faster charge/less safe?  Would a 1amp fuse be slower charge but safer(ie blow at lower threshold)?  I am using 18G wire.

Comment: @syntax: The fuse should be rated a little higher than the expected current, so it won't blow under normal use - for your 1 amp charger, I might use a 2 amp fuse.  The fuse rating will have no effect on the rate of charge.

Comment: Is it safe to use a 10amp fuse? At the point of a short, what would the current be on a 12V battery/charger emitting 1amp?  When there is a short does current spike? or is it the charge? voltage stays constant in series?

Comment: @syntax How safe that fuse would be depends on the type of the fuse. A fast-blow 10 A fuse would be better than no fuse, but I myself would like a lower value fuse if possible. A slow-blow fuse rated at 10 A would again in my opinion be better than no fuse, but I'd consider it less much less safe than a fast fuse.

Comment: @syntax: In case of short circuit, the situation is a bit complex depending on where the short is. What basically happens is that you get a large current spike. That current will heat up conductors and can damage them and their insulation. It can also damage battery. The fuse, whose rating should be lower than the current, of the short circuit, would go into open state when the current gets above its rating and prevent the current from flowing.

Comment: @syntax: As for the charger, I'd connect the positive of the charger to the positive of the battery. Still, it would be great if you would provide a good image of the charger and battery, since in that case I would be able to provide answer with greater certainty.

Comment: @AndrejaKo i put a schematic up in the edit to question.  I went to local store they only had 2amp high voltage... giving it a try... will this work? my config has two fuses on it during charging(one off the charger, one off the battery).

Comment: do you mean take a picture with my camera? or a schematic?

Comment: @syntax Two fuses shouldn't be a problem, since the only one of them should blow. I meant a picture with a camera, so that we can see what type of battery is it exactly, how charger connection looks like and so on. Also try to make the camera focus on text and on circuit components.

Comment: Hi, checked system.  14.5V at charger end post-fuse, and 0V at battery end.  At that end there are quick-connectors.  Basically I pushed the copper into them, crimped, and soldered the wire to the quick-connector.  Or my fuse is not inserted properly?

Comment: yep, it was the fuse! i misordered mini-blades fuses and a regular blade fuse holder... anyhow, thanks for getting me through.